# Pandas get_dummies altering shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I want to one-hot encode the categorical features of my Pandas dataframe. Previously, the values stored variables of shape (60,). See code below:

```
ohe_features = ["Gender", "Married", "Self_Employed"]
num_features = ["Dependents"]

df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=ohe_features, dtype=int)
```

After calling `get_dummies` the `df` now has columns with the following shape:

```
Column 'Gender_Female' has shape (60, 2)
Column 'Gender_Male' has shape (60, 2)
Column 'Married_No' has shape (60, 2)
Column 'Married_Yes' has shape (60, 2)
Column 'Self_Employed_No' has shape (60, 2)
Column 'Self_Employed_Yes' has shape (60, 2)
```

How do I encode the categorical variables without altering the original dimensions of the feature?

**Reproducible Example:**

```
Dependents  Gender  Married Self_Employed
0          Female  Yes      No
```

Comment: please give a reproducible example of `df`

Comment: "Without altering the original dimension of the feature" -> `df['Gender'] = pd.factorize(df['Gender'])[0]`, basically you enumerate the categories. But that might not work very well in some models.

Comment: `Column 'Gender_Female' has shape (60, 2)` makes no sense ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want have original dimensions of the feature, you need sklearn Preprocessing: LabelEncoder(). However, you need know what is the difference between LabelEncoder() and pandas get_dummies:

Example LabelEncoder():

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

 bridge_types = ('Arch','Beam','Truss','Cantilever','Tied 
 Arch','Suspension','Cable')
 df = pd.DataFrame(bridge_types, columns=['Bridge_Types'])

 labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
 df['Bridge_Types_Cat'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df['Bridge_Types'])
 df
```

More info: [Link](https://towardsdatascience.com/categorical-encoding-using-label-encoding-and-one-hot-encoder-911ef77fb5bd)